# Humanity icon instead of Symbolic for USB devices in Nautilus sidebar, Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: usb, nautilus, icons

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 installed. USB devices in Nautilus sidebar are shown in "color", as it was before in 12.04.
Screenshot (USB is called TV SHOWS):
[image]

I think the needed icon is located there:
/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/devices/drive-harddisk-usb-symbolic.svg

So maybe there's kind of script or something that could help.

Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "color"? Looks pretty black and white to me

Comment: Strange, but in a root mode (sudo nautilus) the correct icon is shown.

Comment: I mean Humanity icon for device instead of Symbolic one. The icon of USB device is meant to be the same as for HDD drives, according to what is included in the folder "/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/devices/".